# Passing multi-dimensional arrays to functions in C

Tags: c, arrays, array-address

Why is it necessary to specify the number of elements of a C-array when it is passed as a parameter to a function (10 in the following example)?

```
void myFun(int arr[][10]) {}
```

Is it so because the number of elements is needed to determine the address of the cell being accessed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It's because `arr[i][j]` means `((int *)arr)[i * N + j]` if `arr` is an `int [][N]`: the pointer-arithmetic requires the length of a row.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler needs to have an idea when the next row starts in memory (as a 2D array is just a continuous chunk of memory, one row after the other). The compiler is not psyche!

Answer (score 1):

It is only necessary if you used static allocation for your array thought. Because the generate code create a continuous memory block for the array, like pointed out ruakh.

However if you use dynamic allocation it is not necessary, you only need to pass pointers.

Regards